# Can I distinguish `DispatchGroup` async tasks completion?

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency

Suppose I have three async functions A, B, C.

I want a callback after completion of these three, I will use `DispatchGroup`.

But I have a batch of these async tasks A, B, C. Suppose, 6 of them.

Now I want a callback after each of these A, B, C async task completion.

Like,

```
A
B
C
Callback
A
B
C
Callback
A
B
C
Callback
```

Using `DispatchGroup`, I am getting,

```
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
Callback
```

as `group,notify()` works only when everyone have `group.leave()`.

Sample,

```swift
// Called 6 times

private func fetchLists(in room: Room, 
completion: @escaping(                                                                   _ ownerList: [Any], 
_ memberList: [Any],
_ subscribersList: [Any]) -> Void) {

        var ownerList = [Any]()
        var memberList = [Any]()
        var subscribersList = [Any]()
        
        let group = DispatchGroup()

        group.enter()
        // Asyncronous
        fetchOwners(in: room, completion: { list in
            ownerList = list
            group.leave()
        })
        
        group.enter()
        // Asyncronous
        fetchMembers(in: room, completion: { list in
            memberList = list
            group.leave()
        })
        
        group.enter()
        // Asyncronous
        fetchSubscribers(in: room, completion: { list in
            subscribersList = list
            group.leave()
        })
    
        debug("Called 6 times")
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            debug("Called 1 time. Want it to be called 6 times each with 3 batch.")
            completion(memberList, ownerList, subscribersList)
        }
    }
```

Comment: post your code ...

Comment: Seems like you just need 3 dispatch groups, but do also consider using Combine for this. In any case, please show a [mcve].

Comment: Please, have a look at it now.

Comment: I don't see a loop, so it's unclear why it should be called 6 times.

Comment: Calling it 6 times was just an example. Suppose, I want to create an object with 3 async API calls. Now I want to create a batch of those objects in a single call. Loop was erased. Written as a comment.

Comment: I'd embed the calls `fetchLists(in:completion:)` with a DispatchGroup, with `enter()`  before the method call and `leave()` in the completion. That's why I where is the for loop might be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

As per `DispatchGroup`'s [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup/2016066-notify) the notify method is called when group is empty, which means you have to call `group.leave()` as many times as you have called `group.enter()`. For your scenario, since you want to notify group each time a batch operation completes you have to use a separate group for each batch of tasks.